# Leaflet.js add/remove control from Map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am attempting to combine two fine plugins [Leaflet Easy Button](http://cliffcloud.github.io/Leaflet.EasyButton/) and [Leaflet Routing Machine](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine)and i can't quite get it to work. what I want seems simple enough, I would like to have a button that when clicked adds and removes the routing control to the map. currently I can add the button and control and have the button remove it but I dont know how to get some sweet toggle like functionality.

I am currently stuck with this:

```
var route = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [

    ],
    units: 'imperial',
    geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.google(),
    routeWhileDragging: true
  }).addTo(map);



  L.easyButton('fa-compass',
  function (){route.removeFrom(map)},

  'Routing'
);
```

Also, I have tried manipulating the DOM elements using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507737/adding-removing-l-control-from-leaflet-js-map) post but I havent had any luck.

Comment: is the full source available somewhere? Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I am trying to get a gitpage up but in the meantime it can be downloaded from here.  https://github.com/davemetzler/mystruggle/tree/master/leaflet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the easy button function to:

```
L.easyButton('fa-compass',
  function (){
    $('.leaflet-routing-container').is(':visible') ? route.removeFrom(map) : route.addTo(map)
  },
  'Routing'
);
```

This just applies a simple ternary operator to determine whether to add or remove the route control (and uses jQuery to detect the visibility of the routing container).

Comment: than you Toms. works like a charm.